# Google Calendar: How to check guest is not busy and available to book through google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am exploring to write google calendar api integration through google scripts or apis.

Is there a way I can check a guest is available before I book an event ?

Comment: You would require access to the other users calendar to see their free/busy time; something possible in Google Apps for Business. Just use Google Calendar API, specifying the user's calendar id (usually their email id). Not possible in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Google Apps for Business + Google Apps for Education (for info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in google script using freebusy api like this

```
  var resource = {
    timeMin: timeMin,
    timeMax: timeMax,
    items: [
      {
        id: calendarId
      }
    ]
  };

  var response = Calendar.Freebusy.query(resource);
  return response.calendars[calendarId]['busy'].length == 0;
```